# Determine the smallest symmetric group for this condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

a) Determine the smallest symmetric group $S_n$ that contains a subgroup isomorphic to H, generated by $x^4=y^3=1$, $xy=y^2x$.

b) Find a subgroup of $SL_2(F_5)$ that is isomorphic to that group.

My first step was to say that $n$ is at least 4 so that $S_n$ contains an element of order 4. But I tried $S_4$ and it didn't quite work. After that I couldn't make much progress.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: My answer to this question can also be read as a hint for a): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233939/dicyclic-group-as-subgroup-of-s-6/233994#233994

Comment: @Micah Could you elaborate? Do you mean there is no such $S_n$?

Comment: $H$ is a finite group, so it certainly embeds in $S_n$ for some $n$ (by Cayley's theorem). I think if you experiment with some simple cycle types for $y$, and how it's possible for $x$ to conjugate $y$ appropriately while still having order $4$, it shouldn't be too tough to come up with the smallest possible $S_n$.

Comment: @Micah is it $S_{12}$?

Comment: No it's not $S_{12}$. You know from an earlier question that $n>6$, so why not try $n=7$.

Comment: @DerekHolt y must have cycle type $(abc)(def)....$ so on with disjoint 3-cycles right? So $y^2$ must be $(acb)(dfe)....$ and then the conjugation necessary works out to be $(bc)(ef)...$ I'm not sure where I'm getting it wrong. –

Comment: Try $y$ with a single cycle $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh righttt why didn't I think of that. Thank you!
Any hint on the subgroup of $SL_2(F_5)$?

Answer (score 1):

just for a)

because just need to find some matrices for b)

as we all know, we need 4-cycles to satisfy $x^{4}=1$, so $n≥4$

(or through the order $12|4!, 3!|12$)

but we need a pair of very very *symmetric* permutations $x,y$ to satisfy $x^{4}=1,y^{3}=1,xy=y^{-1}x$

so $n$ need to be $lcm(4,3)=12$

here's an example:

for the set of indexes $\left\{\textbf{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 x y z}\right\}$

$Π_{0}=x=(\textbf{1 2 3 4})(\textbf{5 6 7 8})(\textbf{9 x y z})$

$Π_{1}=y=(\textbf{1 5 9})(\textbf{2 x 6})(\textbf{3 7 y})(\textbf{4 z 8})$

accordingly,$Π_{2}=y^{-1}=(\textbf{1 9 5})(\textbf{2 6 x})(\textbf{3 y 7})(\textbf{4 8 z})$

and the multiplication table:

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\ &\textbf{1}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{5}&\textbf{6}&\textbf{7}&\textbf{8}&\textbf{9}&\textbf{x}&\textbf{y}&\textbf{z}\\
\hline Π_{1}&\textbf{5}&\textbf{x}&\textbf{7}&\textbf{z}&\textbf{9}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{y}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{1}&\textbf{6}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{8}\\
\hline Π_{0}Π_{1}&\textbf{6}&\textbf{y}&\textbf{8}&\textbf{9}&\textbf{x}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{z}&\textbf{1}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{7}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{5}\\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\ &\textbf{1}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{5}&\textbf{6}&\textbf{7}&\textbf{8}&\textbf{9}&\textbf{x}&\textbf{y}&\textbf{z}\\
\hline Π_{0}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{1}&\textbf{6}&\textbf{7}&\textbf{8}&\textbf{5}&\textbf{x}&\textbf{y}&\textbf{z}&\textbf{9}\\
\hline Π_{2}Π_{0}&\textbf{6}&\textbf{y}&\textbf{8}&\textbf{9}&\textbf{x}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{z}&\textbf{1}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{7}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{5}\\
\end{array}

so $Π_{0}Π_{1}=Π_{2}Π_{0}$, that is, $xy=y^{-1}x$

according to the fact, we know $n≤12$

for some permutations not so *symmetric*, just like in $S_5,S_7...$, it's obvious to see whether $n$ is what we want

so we just show why $n≠6$

there's no quite *symmetric* 4-cycle-3-cycle-pair in $S_6$, so we just give not so *symmetric* but tending to be quite *symmetric* permutations

for the set of indexes $\left\{\textbf{1 2 3 4 5 6}\right\}$

$Π_{0}=x=(\textbf{1 2 3 4})(\textbf{5 6})$

$Π_{1}=y=(\textbf{1 3 5})(\textbf{2 6 4})$

$Π_{2}=y^{-1}=(\textbf{1 5 3})(\textbf{2 4 6})$

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\ &\textbf{1}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{5}&\textbf{6}\\
\hline Π_{1}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{6}&\textbf{5}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{1}&\textbf{4}\\
\hline Π_{0}Π_{1}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{5}&\textbf{6}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{1}\\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\ &\textbf{1}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{5}&\textbf{6}\\
\hline Π_{0}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{3}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{1}&\textbf{6}&\textbf{5}\\
\hline Π_{2}Π_{0}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{1}&\textbf{6}&\textbf{5}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{3}\\
\end{array}

$Π_{0}Π_{1}≠Π_{2}Π_{0}$, that is, $xy≠y^{-1}x$ in $S_6$

Comment: for b), $x=\begin{pmatrix}2&\\&3\end{pmatrix}$, $y=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\&1\end{pmatrix}$